# Grouping contents of similar nodes in an XML using XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

I'm using the below XML

```
<Root>
<sample>1</sample>
<sample>2</sample>
<sample>3</sample>
<sample>4</sample>
<sample>5</sample>
<sample>6</sample>
</Root>
```

I want to get the output as given below

```
<sample>123456</sample>
```

I'm using the below XSLT to get the above output. But I'm getting the output like this.

```
<sample>1</sample>
<sample>23456</sample>
<sample>2</sample>
<sample>3456</sample>
<sample>3</sample>
<sample>456</sample>
<sample>4</sample>
<sample>56</sample>
<sample>5</sample>
<sample>6</sample
><sample>6</sample>
<sample></sample>
```

This is the XSL code I have tried:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:template match="sample">
<presample>
<xsl:value-of select="."/>
<xsl:variable name="code" select="following-sibling::sample" />
<xsl:for-each select="following-sibling::sample">
<xsl:if test="not(preceding-sibling::sample)">
<xsl:value-of select="."/>
</xsl:if>
</xsl:for-each>
</presample>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Please help me in correcting this XSLT to get the desired output mentioned above.

Comment: user1968895, You may be interested in a more efficient grouping method, such as Muenchian.

Answer (score 2):

How's this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:template match="sample[1]">
    <sample>
      <xsl:for-each select=". | following-sibling::sample">
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </sample>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="sample[position() > 1]" />
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I imagine your ultimate goal is a bit more involved than this, so if you can elaborate on that there may be a better general approach.

Not sure if this is what you're going for, but here's a potential more generic approach:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:template match="*[text()[normalize-space(.)] and not(name(preceding-sibling::*[1]) = name())]">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:variable name="list" select=". | following-sibling::*"/>
      <xsl:for-each select="$list">
        <xsl:variable name="pos" select="position()" />
        <xsl:if test="not($list[position() &lt; $pos and name() != name(current())])">
          <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        </xsl:if>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="*[name(preceding-sibling::*[1]) = name()]" />
  <xsl:template match="text()" />
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When run on this:

```
<Root>
  <sample>1</sample>
  <sample>2</sample>
  <sample>3</sample>
  <sample>4</sample>
  <sample>5</sample>
  <sample>6</sample>
  <child>
    <something>4</something>
    <something>5</something>
    <something>6</something>
    <something>7</something>
    <somethingelse>a</somethingelse>
    <somethingelse>b</somethingelse>
    <somethingelse>c</somethingelse>
    <somethingelse>d</somethingelse>
    <something>8</something>
    <something>9</something>
    <something>10</something>
  </child>
</Root>
```

Produces this:

```
<sample>123456</sample>
<something>4567</something>
<somethingelse>abcd</somethingelse>
<something>8910</something>
```

Comment: Good going @JLR :) lots of contribution in just 9 days in SO!

Comment: @InfantPro'Aravind' Thanks!  I'm glad I'm able to make myself useful. :-)

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="sample[not(preceding-sibling::sample)]">
    <sample>
      <xsl:for-each select=". | following-sibling::sample">
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </sample>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="sample[preceding-sibling::sample]" />
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

for input XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<root>
  <sample>1</sample>
  <sample>2</sample>
  <sample>3</sample>
  <sample>4</sample>
  <dummy1>a</dummy1>
  <dummy2>b</dummy2>
  <dummy3>c</dummy3>
  <dummy4>d</dummy4>
  <sample>5</sample>
  <sample>6</sample>
  <sample>7</sample>
  <sample>8</sample>
</root>
```

And the output will be:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<root>
  <sample>12345678</sample>
  <dummy1>a</dummy1>
  <dummy2>b</dummy2>
  <dummy3>c</dummy3>
  <dummy4>d</dummy4>
</root>
```

Answer (score 0):

**This is a simple application of the Muenchian grouping method -- a significantly more efficient grouping method than using a sibling axis**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
 <xsl:key name="kSampleByVal" match="sample" use="."/>

 <xsl:template match="sample[1]" priority="2">
  <sample>
   <xsl:apply-templates select=
   "../*[generate-id()=generate-id(key('kSampleByVal',.)[1])]/text()"/>
  </sample>
 </xsl:template>
 <xsl:template match="*/*"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When this transformation is applied on the following XML document** (the provided one modified to be made more representative):

```
<Root>
    <sample>1</sample>
    <sample>2</sample>
    <sample>3</sample>
    <sample>4</sample>
    <sample>5</sample>
    <sample>6</sample>
    <sample>3</sample>
    <sample>4</sample>
    <sample>1</sample>
    <sample>2</sample>
    <sample>3</sample>
</Root>
```

**the wanted, correct result is produced**:

```
<sample>123456</sample>
```

**Do note**:

**I recommend using the Muenchian grouping method over siblings comparisson grouping in all cases.** Muenchian has O(N) time complexity, while the time complexity of siblings-comparisson grouping is quadratical -- O(N^2). I have seen a sibling-comparisson grouping take 40 minutes, while the Muenchian grouping took just 2 seconds.

Comment: @IanRoberts, Thanks for letting me know -- I am still a little bit sleepy this morning. Fixed.